# Matching "curly" quotes against standard quotes in DB query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have text stored in `post_title` column:

```
you’re
```

Using this query:

```
function ma_post_title_filter($where, &$wp_query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'ma_search_post_title' ) ) {
        $search_term = sanitize_text_field($search_term);
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

If `$search_term` is `you’re`, it works and finds the column. But when it is `you're`, it does not work (because it is a different single quotation mark).

How can I improve the query so both `you’re` and `you're` matches with `you’re`?

### What I've tried so far

1. Use `str_replace()` on `$search_term` to replace `'` with `’`. Example: `str_replace('\'','’',$wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ))`... the problem with this approach is that we will never match if the stored column is `you're`.
2. Do `AND REPLACE` on `'.$wpdb->posts.'.post_title` to replace `'` with `’`... but doesn't seem to work.

I'm aware the ideal solution is to adjust all the database instances of the single quotation to a standard one but this is not possible in my case.

What's the proper solution to this?

Comment: The *What I've tried so far* section is lovely. Should be standard here. +1

Comment: Probs not suitable as you don't know if that's the search term every time, so I deleted the comment ;)

Comment: Did you try to replace `’` with `'` since your pattern is `'.post_title LIKE \'%'`?

Comment: @forpas Replacing it when exactly? Please see my two example approaches and notes about why it did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Your pattern is this: `'.post_title LIKE \'%'` meaning you're trying to match with `'`, right? So you apply `str_replace('’', ''', $search_term)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to point out that `%` is not the only placeholder that can be used in `LIKE` queries. You can use the underscore `_` to indicate a single character as well. One approach could be to replace every punctuation character in a certain class with an underscore. This would allow "you're" to match "you’re" and vice-versa. (Granted, it would also allow "youvre" to match as well!)

```
<?php
function ma_post_title_filter($where, &$wp_query) {
    global $wpdb;
    $punct = ["’", "‘", "”", "“"];
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'ma_search_post_title' ) ) {
        // escape any % or _ characters
        $search_term = $wpdb->esc_like($search_term);
        // replace desired punctuation characters with _
        $search_term = str_replace($punct, "_", $search_term);
        // do final escaping for safe queries
        $search_term = $wpdb->_real_escape($search_term);
        // this looks much neater with string interpolation vs concatenation
        $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$search_term%'";
    }
    return $where;
}
```

You should, when passing values to a `LIKE` clause, use [`wpdb::esc_like()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/) to ensure any user-supplied percent signs or underscores don't get in the way of things. [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) is meant to be used before output to HTML, and does nothing to make text safe for a database query. That's what [`wpdb::_real_escape()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_real_escape/) is for.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent approach, but it is not working. Is there a typo in `$where`? Here is [an example code](https://pastebin.com/wnUXCsE9) you can use to test this. I feel the issue is likely a typo as the code itself is very logic!

Comment: Removing the `$wpdb->real_escape($search_term);` part seem to at least allow the code to run. But `$string_term = "you're";`is still not matching with a post with title `you’re`.

Comment: I don’t have a way to test this but I’d suggest printing out `$search_term` at various points through the code, and doing the same to see what `$where` looks like.

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you running?

Comment: I am using the latest version.

Comment: Ok just realized a typo. Leading underscore missing before `_real_escape()`

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error. But `$string_term = "you're";` is still not matching with `you’re`. Maybe this replaces the quotes on the search term variable, but not the stored title in the db? Just a wild guess.

Comment: It's not meant to replace anything on the database side. You should end up with `$where` looking like `AND posts.post_title LIKE '%you_re%' `. Adding a simple `die($where)` in place of the return statement should print out the clause for you to inspect.

Comment: You are right. Did `var_dump()` on `$where` and discovered that `$search_term` had backward slashes in it. Resolved it with `$search_term = stripslashes($search_term);`... going to finally put this into test and see if it works. Thank you! EDIT: Looks like `youvre` is not matching. Any way to adjust the code so it matches with that as well?

Comment: Your search term needs backslashes to escape special characters, that’s what `_real_escape()` does. When I mentioned a spurious match like “youvre” i was referring to the database contents, not the search term.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL RLIKE :

```
$where .= ' AND '. $wpdb->posts .'.post_title RLIKE \'.\*'. $wpdb->esc_like(str_replace(["’","'"],"['’]", $search_term) ) .'.\*\' ';
```

Comment: OP already said they can't change the existing data, but use of `RLIKE` is a good idea; you should edit your post to make your code more readable and it should get some upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would be using twice a `LIKE` statement, one with the original search term, the second one with a replacement of the `'` by `’`

You can use parameterized queries. In example, using [wpdb::prepare()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) :

```
$searchTerm = "You're"; //Don't sanitize using a function, this will by done with parameters.
// query
$where .= ' AND ('. $wpdb->posts .'.post_title LIKE %s OR '. $wpdb->posts .'.post_title LIKE %s)'; //Notice the double %s
//I suppose $where contains your whole query
$sth = $wpdb->prepare($where, '%' . $searchTerm . '%', '%' . str_replace('’', '\'', $search_term) . '%'); //This will associate the %s (a string) in the query by the value indicated in the function
$wpdb->query($sth);
```

The `%s` is a [placeholder](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders) in the query to indicate to `$wpdb->prepare()` that there will be a string at this place.

Comment: Thanks but can you kindly edit your answer with examples of how to adjust my specific code with your approach?

Comment: Sure, wait a moment

Comment: @Cid FYI, the OP is using WordPress [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)....

Comment: @GaryWoods thank you, I adapted my answer to this situation

Comment: Looks like I forgot to take in consideration a part of the question.

Comment: @Cid This is [my actual code](https://pastebin.com/ieFE38ky). Note sure if `prepare` work to add in this function?

Comment: Yeah using prepared statements is always the best approach, but Wordpress makes this very difficult to do. The function in the original question is applied dynamically by WP when there's a search query involved, so the actual execution is handled elsewhere.